# Preserve newlines in file rendered to HTML with Jinja

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am trying to print the content of a file in a web page.  I want to print each line from the file on a separate line, but instead the line breaks are missing.  How do I print the file and preserve newlines?

```
@app.route('/users')
def print_users():
    v = open("users.txt","r").read().strip()
    # also tried:
    # v = open("users.txt","r").read().strip().split('\n')
    return render_template('web.html', v=v)
```

```
{{ v|safe}}
```

Comment: use `readlines()` to get a list of lines

Comment: But how to print each line separately? any code example?

Comment: put a for loop in your html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
v = open("users.txt","r").readlines()
v = [line.strip() for line in v]
```

and then in your html something like (but feel free to play around with it):

```
<form action="/print_users"  method="post" >    
                    <div class="form-inline">

                  {% for line in v %}
                      <div>{{ line|safe}}</div>
                  {% endfor %}


    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  value="submit" > 
              </div>

                    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers give great techniques and the current accepted solution works, I needed to do a similar task (rendering a text email template), but needed to extend this to preserve the processing of macros within the file, which led me to create what I think is the simplest and most elegant solution - using render_template_string.

```
def show_text_template(template_name):
    """
    Render a text template to screen.
    Replace newlines with <br> since rendering a template to html will lose the line breaks
    :param template_name: the text email template to show
    :return: the text email, rendered as a template
    """
    from flask import render_template_string

    txt_template = open(
        '{}/emails/{}{}'.format(app.config.root_path + '/' + app.template_folder, template_name, '.txt'),
        "r").readlines()

    return render_template_string('<br>'.join(txt_template))
```